# how can i detect touch on already selected UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone

how can i detect touch on already selected UIBarButtonItem?
if i touch UIBarButtonItem , it will be selected..but if i touch the same again,
how can i identify it ? any help please?

the code is as follows.. initWithCustomView:sortToggle in which sortToggle is segmented control...

```
 UIBarButtonItem *sortToggleButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                         initWithCustomView:sortToggle];
 [sortToggle release];

 UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                       target:nil
                                       action:nil];

 NSArray *buttonArray = [NSArrayarrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceButtonItem, 
                                                 sortToggleButtonItem, 
                                                 flexibleSpaceButtonItem, nil];

 [self setToolbarItems: buttonArray animated:YES];
```

Comment: You need to be a little bit more descriptive about your question. Is this a segmented control? Is this a single custom multi barbutton?

Comment: i have added code...UIbarbuttonitem which has UIsegmentedcontrol view

Comment: this is theft my dear. beware u dont misuse anybodies code and say it as urs....

Comment: i did not steal..i got this code from net to use in my project.... ok.....pls remove your comment....i dont whether the website has used your code or not......i did not mention that is my code..ok

Answer (score 1):

The UIBarButtonItem does not inherit from the UIResponder so you can not get touchesBegan / touchedEnded etc events directly. If you set the UISegmentedControl to be momentary (`yourSegControl.momentary = YES`) you can select a button more than once. Is this helpful for your situation?

Otherwise, you should probably subclass the UISegmentedControl (which inherits from the UIResponder) and handle the extra touches yourself (don't forget to call super in any touch method you override).

Comment: any tutorial sir..?to handle it..?please..?

Comment: Did you try setting the .momentary property to YES?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to be able to detect when the user selected an already selected index, and I found the problem was that the **UISegmentedControl** only fired the **UIControlEventValueChanged** event. I wanted to be able to get the **UIControlEventTouchUpInside** event so I could do something.

The solution is to subclass **UISegmentedControl** and overwrite the touch event to fire the event you want.

Create a subclass of **UISegmentedControl** and override **touchesBegan:withEvent:**...

```
/* MySegmentedControl.m, a subclass of UISegmentedControl... */
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  //dont forget to call super!
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
  //fire the event we want to listen to
  [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Then listen for the **UIControlEventTouchUpInside** of your segmented control instead of **UIControlEventValueChanged** so that you only get one event fired...otherwise it will fire the UIControlEventValueChanged event once naturally, and once when you fire it, and you'll get two events (which you obviously don't want).

```
[mySegmentedControlInstance addTarget:self action:@selector(mySegmentedControlSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

This way you get an event once every time the control is touched, not just when it's value is changed.

Comment: and no, you don't need to set the .momentary property for the above to work because you are taking control of the touch events directly.